# Jenkins not building github project

Tags: github, jenkins, ubuntu-12.04

ok, so, before I explain my issue, I must mention that I am fairly new to jenkins and github, both.. The issue is, I have managed to attach jenkins Job with github project, but when I try to build the job on jenkins, I get the following error to my email:

```
     Started by user anonymous
        Building in workspace <http://127.0.0.1:8080/job/work_test/ws/>
        Checkout:workspace / <http://127.0.0.1:8080/job/work_test/ws/> - hudson.remoting.LocalChannel@7932e6fd
        Using strategy: Default
        Fetching changes from 1 remote Git repos

itory
    Fetching upstream changes from git@github.com:[user]/[project]-portal.git
    Seen branch in repository origin/HEAD
    Seen branch in repository origin/develop
    Seen branch in repository origin/development_umair
    Seen branch in repository origin/logs_redesign
    Seen branch in repository origin/master
    Seen branch in repository origin/overviewtabs
    Commencing build of Revision b65f1a84d55a048accbcf7af2f56bb357fe73b64 (origin/overviewtabs)
    Checking out Revision b65f1a84d55a048accbcf7af2f56bb357fe73b64 (origin/overviewtabs)
    FATAL: Could not apply tag jenkins-[project name]_test-17
hudson.plugins.git.GitException: Could not apply tag [project name] test-17
    at hudson.plugins.git.GitAPI.tag(GitAPI.java:829)
    at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM$4.invoke(GitSCM.java:1270)
    at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM$4.invoke(GitSCM.java:1231)
    at hudson.FilePath.act(FilePath.java:852)
    at hudson.FilePath.act(FilePath.java:825)
    at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM.checkout(GitSCM.java:1231)
    at hudson.model.AbstractProject.checkout(AbstractProject.java:1325)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.defaultCheckout(AbstractBuild.java:682)
    at jenkins.scm.SCMCheckoutStrategy.checkout(SCMCheckoutStrategy.java:88)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.run(AbstractBuild.java:587)
    at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1543)
    at hudson.model.FreeStyleBuild.run(FreeStyleBuild.java:46)
    at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:88)
    at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:236)
    Caused by: hudson.plugins.git.GitException: Command "git tag a -f -m Jenkins Build #17 jenkins[project name]_test-17" returned status code 128:
    stdout:
    stderr:
    Please tell me who you are.
    Run
    git config --global user.email "you@example.com"
    git config --global user.name "Your Name"
    to set your account's default identity.
    Omit --global to set the identity only in this repository.
    fatal: empty ident <jenkins@[email]-KJ419AA-AB4-a6417l.(none)> not allowed
    at hudson.plugins.git.GitAPI.launchCommandIn(GitAPI.java:897)
    at hudson.plugins.git.GitAPI.launchCommand(GitAPI.java:858)
    at hudson.plugins.git.GitAPI.launchCommand(GitAPI.java:868)
    at hudson.plugins.git.GitAPI.tag(GitAPI.java:827)
    ... 13 more
```

Need detailed yet easy for a new be to configure type of help.. =) i have searched for the solution , but the closest I got was the importance of having "gitconfig" file. I tried to configure it, but was unable to solve the issue... and also to mention, i am using ubuntu OS if that's some what related to the solution..